# Quordle: Killer Guess

Tags: word, letters, wordle

The last time I played [Quordle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/games/quordle/#/), I didn't perfectly match any of the four words on my first guess. But my first guess did give me enough information to fully deduce the solution. (Note that a solution to a Quordle puzzle is an *ordered* list of four words.)

What might my guess and the solution have been?

Assume that the four solution words are guaranteed to all be different.

There's some ambiguity about what words are allowed in Quordle. For this puzzle, let's just say that plurals are allowed, and that every word making up an answer should be obviously more common than every word whose legality would invalidate the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example for your first guess could have been

> BATES

With the matches for the four words being as follows

> 

From this, it's very easy to work out the words, in order, are

> BETAS
>  TABES
>  BEATS
>  ABETS

I had to check and all of these are valid guesses in Wordle, as of the current version. There may be many other possible solutions